# Show included php pages of a request?

Tags: php, debugging

I wonder if it's possible in some way to know and eventually show all the php pages processed during a single http request.

For example, if the page is /index.php I'd like to call the page and to know immediately what are all the included php pages required to get the response, without obviously debugging the page...

Maybe through logs, or dump?

Comment: The `get_included_files` function should do the job. You should also take a look at [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/).

Comment: @hsz I try to go off-line on weekends...:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [`get_included_files`](http://php.net/get_included_files) method.

> Gets the names of all files that have been included using include, include_once, require or require_once.

Comment: Amazing. I've done PHP sites going back to ??? and I never knew this was there. I use the Python-equivalent all the time and have often wished for this. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterRowell If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with marking the tick on the left.

Comment: I would, but I'm not the OP. The best I can offer is an up-vote, which I've already done.